# How to check the output after heroku pg:sql?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to run a select statement on a Postgres database on a free Heroku app.

I am running these commands commands in `cmd`:

1. Log in to heroku
2. `chcp 1252`
3. `heroku pg:psql -app "my-app-name::DATABASE"`

I then get prompted by:

```
--> Connecting to postgresql-rectangular-44045
psql (13.4)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.
```

And I can now write to `my-app-name::DATABASE=>` but regardless of what I write I don't get a response just another line starting with `my-app-name::DATABASE->`. I also checked the Heroku application logs (all processes) to see if the output got printed there but it was empty.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And I can now write to `my-app-name::DATABASE=>` but regardless of what I write I don't get a response just another line starting with `my-app-name::DATABASE->`

Those two prompts are subtly different: the first ends with `=>` and the second with `->`.

The `->` prompt indicates that `psql` is waiting for more input for the same query, e.g. in case you want to split your query up into several lines for readability.

Make sure to terminate each query with `;` so `psql` knows you're done.

See [the first example here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-EXAMPLES) for more.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the `;`. So pressing enter without `;` would just create a multiline query/command?

Comment: Yep! There are other prompts too, e.g. if you open a `(` and then hit enter. Finish the whole query, terminate with `;`, and hit enter.